# Class from addClass() not working using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this code

```
$('.button').click(function(){
    $('.ic84').addClass("deletexxx");
});
$('.deletexxx').click(function(){
    $('body').hide();
});
```

```html
<button class="button">Test number 1</button>
<button class="ic84">Test number 2</button>
```

Why after I click `.button` then click `.ic84` the event handler for `.deletexxx` does not work. Can anyone tell me why this is?

Comment: use event delegation

Comment: Because at time you are trying to bind click event, there is no element with that class. Delegate event to process selector 'on the fly'

Comment: What are you expecting `$('body').hide();` to do?

Comment: Thank you , the problem has been resolved :v

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('.button').click(function() {
  $('.ic84').addClass("deletexxx");
});
$(document).on('click','.deletexxx',function() {
  alert('Hide body')
  $('body').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button">Test number 1</button>
<button class="ic84">Test number 2</button>
```

Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (passing relevant selector param string) for element that is not present on page load

Answer (score 1):

The way you are attaching your click event is incorrect for your specific situation.

```
jQuery('.myclass').click(function(e){});
```

Will search all elements in your current DOM for an element with the class ".myClass" and then attach the click to it. In your situation, this will not work because at the moment you are trying to attach this event, there is no element with the given class yet... so no event is attached.

The solution for this is event delegation

```
jQuery('body').on('click', '.myclass', function(e){});
```

What this does is that it adds an event listener to the body (or any other html element) that will listen for any click on an element that has the class .myclass. (this works the same way as you can click on a "span" element that is wrapped in an "a" element,..this will still trigger a click on the "a")

So in your example:

```
$(document).on('click','.deletexxx',function() {
      alert('this works');
  });
```

Is the correct way of triggering.